# How to handle lag date in a loop

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have been trying to clean my data with lag date variables. I want to check my dataset row by row to replace some values of my data if certain conditions are met. My simplified dataset is as follows:

```
DT<-data.table(
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    START_DATE = c("2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-05", "2012-02-01",
             ,"2012-02-20", "2012-03-07", "2012-05-16", "2012-05-16")
    END_DATE = c("2012-01-04","2012-01-04","2012-01-18", "2012-02-19",
             , "2012-03-06", "2012-03-18", "2012-06-02", "2012-06-02")
    )
```

For those END_DATE immediately followed by next START_DATE (e.g. the first three rows), I wanted to change both START_DATE and END_DATE with the function lag() by ID so that I can get new START_DATE and END_DATE as follows:

```
START_DATE = c("2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-01", "2012-02-01",
             ,"2012-02-20", "2012-02-20", "2012-05-16", "2012-05-16")
    END_DATE = c("2012-01-18","2012-01-18","2012-01-18", "2012-02-19",
             , "2012-03-18", "2012-03-18", "2012-06-02", "2012-06-02")
```

I am quite new to R. I have been thinking about group_by, lag(), and for loop, but I wasn't able to combine all of them together and made them work. Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `DATE` columns to `Date` class, then create a grouping column ('grp') based on the difference between the `lag` of the 'START' and 'END' dates grouped by 'ID', use that as grouping to update the columns with the `first` and `last` of 'START', 'END' dates.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, c("START_DATE", "END_DATE") := lapply(.SD, as.IDate),
   .SDcols = patterns("_DATE")]
DT[, grp := cumsum((START_DATE - 
   shift(END_DATE, fill = first(END_DATE))) > 1), ID]
DT[, c("START_DATE", "END_DATE") := .(first(START_DATE), 
    last(END_DATE)), .(ID, grp)]
DT[, grp := NULL]
```

-output

```
> DT
   ID START_DATE   END_DATE
1:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
2:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
3:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
4:  1 2012-02-01 2012-02-19
5:  2 2012-02-20 2012-03-18
6:  2 2012-02-20 2012-03-18
7:  2 2012-05-16 2012-06-02
8:  2 2012-05-16 2012-06-02
```

OP's expected

```
> out
   ID START_DATE   END_DATE
1:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
2:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
3:  1 2012-01-01 2012-01-18
4:  1 2012-02-01 2012-02-19
5:  2 2012-02-20 2012-03-18
6:  2 2012-02-20 2012-03-18
7:  2 2012-05-16 2012-06-02
8:  2 2012-05-16 2012-06-02
```